# Prevent EditText to gain focus on Next button click of soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a fragment view and one fragment have some sets of EditTexts and the another has one EditText as well. The problem I have is, I click Next button in softkeyboard when it is in a EditText, it goes to the next EditText in the same fragment view. But after the third EditText, on Next in softkeyboard, it goes to the Edittext which is in the next fragment view. Vertically, the EditText is just below the 3rd EditText. Is it because of that ?

Comment: I also got the same issue. Did you find a solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: No luck favored me. All I did is, I re-positioned the EditText.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    // do something with next printed on your editText

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The key factor is you return `true` which tells that you have consumed the Next action, so no more focus by default.

```
Returns
Return true if you have consumed the action, else false.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code:

```
youredittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        prepareMonthDialog();
                    }
                }, 500);
               return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```